# Add products with selections directly from category view in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, addtocart

Products without options can be added to cart directly from category view in the default theme.

I would like to be able to add all products directly from category view. Even if they have options for color and size.

Is there such a function in Magento 2?

**Preferable I would like to have a select for color and size and also have a input for quantity.**